# Set up component view with its own values

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have the following code to populate and display a component view within another:

Welcome.js

```
export class Welcome {
  heading = 'Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App!';

  appleNum = 10; <-- Set value of apple num

  buyApples(){
      console.log("Buy Apples");
      console.log(this.appleNum)
  }
}
```

Welcome.html

```
<form role="form" submit.delegate="buyApples()">

    <shop shop-data.bind="appleNum"></shop>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    <p>Number of apples: ${appleNum}</p>
</form>
```

Shop.js

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Shop {
  @bindable shopData;
}
```

Shop.html

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">                        
        <label class="control-label">Number of Apples
            <input id="apple-number" name="apple-number" type="number" class="form-control" value.bind="appleNum">
        </label>
    </div>
</template>
```

This works fine for getting / setting the value of `appleNum`.

[image]

The problem I have is that I want to set the value of appleNum inside `shop.js` (E.g so when `shop` is displayed as an element somewhere, it looks after getting its own data). What I have below is an example of what I want to do but it doesn't work:

Shop.js

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Shop {
  @bindable shopData;

  constructor(){
      //Set intial values of apples
      this.appleNum = 1;
  }
}
```

The initial value is set but can't be updated:

[image: image showing problem]

Does anybody know how I might be able to let the component set up its own values?

**Edit**

I have the following which does what I want but it feels kind of hacky..

shop-info.js

```
export class ShopInfo {
  constructor() {
      this.appleNum = 10;
  }

  resetBasket() {
      this.appleNum = 10;
  }
}
```

welcome.js

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ShopInfo} from "./shop-info"

@inject(ShopInfo)
export class Welcome {
  heading = 'Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App!';

  constructor(shopInfo){
      this.shopInfo = shopInfo;
  }  

  buyApples(){
      this.shopInfo.resetBasket();
  }
}
```

welcome.html

```
<template>
  <require from="./shop"></require>
  <section class="au-animate">

    <form role="form" submit.delegate="buyApples()">
        <shop shop-data.bind="shopInfo.appleNum"></shop>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        <p>Number of apples: ${shopInfo.appleNum}</p>
    </form>
  </section>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you modify the value of `this.appleNum` inside of `shop.js`, `welcome.html` and `welcome.js` can't know about that change because `this.appleNum` inside of `shop.js` is not `@bindable`. To fix the problem you can do this:

welcome.js

```
export class Welcome {
  heading = 'Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App!';

  this.welcomeAppleNum = 10;

  buyApples(){
      console.log("Buy Apples");
      console.log(this.welcomeAppleNum)
  }
}
```

welcome.html

```
<template>
    <require from="./shop"></require>
    <form role="form" submit.delegate="buyApples()">

        <shop shop-apple-num.two-way="welcomeAppleNum"></shop>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        <p>Number of apples: ${welcomeAppleNum}</p>
    </form>
</template>
```

shop.js

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Shop {
  @bindable shopAppleNum;

  constructor(){
      this.shopAppleNum = 1;
  }
}
```

shop.html

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">                        
        <label class="control-label">Number of Apples
            <input id="apple-number" name="apple-number" type="number" class="form-control" value.bind="shopAppleNum">
        </label>
    </div>
</template>
```

Now `welcomeAppleNum` and `shopAppleNum` should stay in sync because they are bound.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - What I'd really like to do is avoid having to set the properties of shop in any classes which use it. For example if I have `view-model1`, `view-model2`, `view-model3` etc. all using `<shop>`, I don't want to define the value of  `AppleNum` in each. You know what I mean?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. You don't *have* to set the value of `this.welcomeAppleNum` like I did. You can do nothing and instead let `shop.js` initialize it.

Comment: I tried your code and the initial value seems to be set but changes are not reflected in the UI

Comment: I think you might have to use an explicit `two-way` binding. In welcome.html try using `<shop shop-apple-num.two-way="welcomeAppleNum"></shop>`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, same problem - UI / value not updated

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you wanted to achieve?
http://plnkr.co/edit/dF1MPs3TiMZ443gYRhEK?p=preview

If so:
First you would need two-way databinding for `appleNum` to be set by `shop`:

```
<shop shop-data.two-way="appleNum"></shop>
```

Or, in shop.js:

```
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Shop {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) shopData;
  ...
}
```

Then, set the value of `shopData` in the `attached()` method:

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Shop {
  @bindable shopData;

  attached() {
    this.shopData = 2;
  }
}
```

The value set in `constructor` is overriden by the value you set in `welcome.js`.